# How does the EnumConverter Constructor get the Type Parameter

Tags: c#, constructor, parameter-passing, typeconverter

If I create a class for customized displaying of an enumeration as follows:

```
public class MyEnumConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public MyEnumConverter(Type type) : base(type)
    {
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(...)
    public override object ConvertFrom(...)
}
```

When I tag an enum with `MyEnumConverter` as the `TypeConverter`:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    SomeValue,
    OtherValue
}
```

It works as expected.  How does the `EnumConverter` constructor receive [the required type parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.enumconverter.enumconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) representing the enum type?  Does `TypeConverter` know how to deal specifically with `EnumConverter` and fill this in for me?  Is this syntactic sugar for something going on in the background?  Is this behaviour customizable such that if I want to implement a parameterized constructor for a custom `TypeConverter`, that I can inform `TypeConverter` how to handle my custom constructor?

Comment: Is this for display in a designer somewhere? The code responsible for that might be in the framework and ILSpy can show you what it does. Very likely it passes the value as an array into a reflected constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, internally, `TypeConverter` handles the procurement of the required converter using a complicated nested `if` statement.  Something like ([source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/WIN_WINDOWS/lh_tools_devdiv_wpf/Windows/wcp/Base/System/Windows/Markup/TypeConverterHelper@cs/1/TypeConverterHelper@cs)):

```
    internal static TypeConverter GetCoreConverterFromCustomType(Type type)
    {
        TypeConverter typeConverter = null;
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            // Need to handle Enums types specially as they require a ctor that
            // takes the underlying type.
            typeConverter = new System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter(type);
        }
        else if (typeof(Int32).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            typeConverter = new System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter();
        }
        else if (typeof(Int16).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            typeConverter = new System.ComponentModel.Int16Converter();
        }
        //...
```

From the first `if` statement you can see that it knows to pass the special `Type` parameter into the constructor.

As an answer to the second question of can I create a custom `TypeConverter` with a custom-parameterized constructor that will play nicely with `TypeConverter`, it looks doubtful.